# Prevent translation of wordpress plugin from being updated

Tags: wordpress

I translated a plugin of wordpress into Japanese by myself and I am afraid that when I update the plugin, I have to translate these codes again and it takes very long time. Is there a way to prevent these codes from being updated?

Comment: You could look into [this free plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/loco-translate/) which keeps the translations in `wp-content/languages/`, safe from updates.

Comment: Thank you very much. I like the plugin.